# XcodeGen integration: iOS APP crash only on testFlight

Tags: swift, react-native, testflight, xcodegen

I have a really  strange issue with my App on testFlight,
I have integrated XcodeGen to improve the project and handle efficiency merge conflicts.
Every thing work fine when I test on develop config both on simulator and device. But When I launch version on test flight, I have a strange crash!!!
this is the report:

```
    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18cd265ac __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a0da042c objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   React                           0x10315e348 0x103154000 + 41800 (RCTAssert.m:146)
3   React                           0x1031756ec __28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke + 716 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:991)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x18c922fd0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1454)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x18c924ac8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x18c93204c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 836 (inline_internal.h:2548)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x18cca31e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1790)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x18cc9d3b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2508 (CFRunLoop.c:3118)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x18cc9c4bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
10  GraphicsServices                0x1a3721820 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2259)
11  UIKitCore                       0x18f640734 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072 (UIApplication.m:3270)
12  UIKitCore                       0x18f645e10 UIApplicationMain + 168 (UIApplication.m:4739)
13  AppOfCards                      0x100b2ea5c main + 68 (APIManager.swift:22)
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x18c963e60 start + 4

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8c4f98c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4277c74 pthread_kill + 272 (pthread.c:1375)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000195e28c34 __abort + 116 (abort.c:147)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000195e28bc0 abort + 116 (abort.c:118)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a0e9fe24 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:76)
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a0e91434 demangling_terminate_handler() + 308 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:67)
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a0da0710 _objc_terminate() + 132 (objc-exception.mm:701)
7   FirebaseCrashlytics             0x000000010273e484 0x10270c000 + 205956
8   FirebaseCrashlytics             0x000000010271c504 FIRCLSTerminateHandler() + 276 (FIRCLSException.mm:333)
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a0e9f2a8 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
10  libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a0e9f234 std::terminate() + 44 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c924adc _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:562)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c93204c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 836 (inline_internal.h:2548)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cca31e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1790)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cc9d3b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2508 (CFRunLoop.c:3118)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cc9c4bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
16  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a3721820 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2259)
17  UIKitCore                       0x000000018f640734 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072 (UIApplication.m:3270)
18  UIKitCore                       0x000000018f645e10 UIApplicationMain + 168 (UIApplication.m:4739)
19  AppOfCards                      0x0000000100b2ea5c main + 68 (APIManager.swift:22)
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018c963e60 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f774 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f774 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cc216dc -[NSMethodSignature _argInfo:] + 0 (NSForwarding.m:2476)
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cc29e68 -[NSMethodSignature _classForObjectAtArgumentIndex:] + 80 (NSForwarding.m:2542)
2   Foundation                      0x000000018e142c4c setProtocolMetadataWithSignature + 336 (NSXPCInterface.m:421)
3   Foundation                      0x000000018e14297c setProtocolMetdataWithMethods + 636 (NSXPCInterface.m:566)
4   Foundation                      0x000000018e140f5c setProtocolMetadata + 328 (NSXPCInterface.m:599)
5   Foundation                      0x000000018e140eb8 setProtocolMetadata + 164 (NSXPCInterface.m:586)
6   Foundation                      0x000000018df1a6a0 -[NSXPCInterface setProtocol:] + 284 (NSXPCInterface.m:630)
7   Foundation                      0x000000018df1a444 +[NSXPCInterface interfaceWithProtocol:] + 52 (NSXPCInterface.m:186)
8   CoreTelephony                   0x000000018d27c020 -[CoreTelephonyClientMux _connect_sync] + 196 (CoreTelephonyClientMux.mm:81)
9   CoreTelephony                   0x000000018d27c5f8 -[CoreTelephonyClientMux _ensureConnectionSetup_sync:] + 44 (CoreTelephonyClientMux.mm:403)
10  CoreTelephony                   0x000000018d27b034 -[CoreTelephonyClientMux initWithSink:] + 252 (CoreTelephonyClientMux.mm:167)
11  CoreTelephony                   0x000000018d27aef4 -[CoreTelephonyClientMux init] + 60 (CoreTelephonyClientMux.mm:154)
12  CoreTelephony                   0x000000018d2820b0 +[CoreTelephonyClient sharedMultiplexer] + 80 (CoreTelephonyClient.mm:45)
13  CoreTelephony                   0x000000018d282120 -[CoreTelephonyClient initWithQueue:] + 44 (CoreTelephonyClient.mm:54)
14  CoreTelephony                   0x000000018d2722dc -[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo init] + 72 (CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.mm:150)
15  AppOfCards                      0x00000001017ced0c 0x100b28000 + 13266188
16  AppOfCards                      0x00000001017d1ee8 0x100b28000 + 13278952
17  AppOfCards                      0x00000001017c8cf8 0x100b28000 + 13241592
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c922fd0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1454)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c924ac8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c92bc08 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 580 (inline_internal.h:2548)
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c92c734 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408 (queue.c:3862)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c936528 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 708 (queue.c:6590)
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4278908 _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2194)
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f77c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f774 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8c2bdd0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8c2b184 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c93ce10 _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply + 528 (mach.c:809)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c93d1ac dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply + 56 (mach.c:1984)
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x00000001d429c9f4 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 240 (connection.c:839)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cd42b38 __104-[CFPrefsSearchListSource synchronouslySendDaemonMessage:andAgentMessage:andDirectMessage:replyHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 40 (CFPrefsSearchListSource.m:1025)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cc0f050 -[_CFXPreferences withConnectionForRole:performBlock:] + 52 (CFXPreferences.m:1386)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cd42ae8 __104-[CFPrefsSearchListSource synchronouslySendDaemonMessage:andAgentMessage:andDirectMessage:replyHandler:]_block_invoke + 140 (CFPrefsSearchListSource.m:1024)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cd4292c CFPREFERENCES_IS_WAITING_FOR_SYSTEM_CFPREFSD + 100 (CFPrefsSearchListSource.m:947)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cd40c48 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource synchronouslySendDaemonMessage:andAgentMessage:andDirectMessage:replyHandler:] + 332 (CFPrefsSearchListSource.m:1044)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cc2a1f4 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_setObservingContents:] + 540 (CFPrefsSearchListSource.m:472)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cc2898c -[CFPrefsSearchListSource addPreferencesObserver:] + 204 (CFPrefsSearchListSource.m:494)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cd44658 __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 404 (CFPrefsSearchListSource.m:1728)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cd43c24 normalizeQuintuplet + 356 (CFPrefsSearchListSource.m:73)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cd4449c -[_CFXPreferences withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 152 (CFPrefsSearchListSource.m:1600)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cc28af4 -[_CFXPreferences registerUserDefaultsInstance:configurationURL:] + 184 (CFXPreferences.m:393)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cd83b28 _CFPrefsRegisterUserDefaultsInstanceWithCloudConfigurationURL + 108 (CFXPreferences.m:1594)
17  Foundation                      0x000000018e018114 _NSKeyValueReplaceObservationInfoForObject + 116 (NSKeyValueObserving.m:1326)
18  Foundation                      0x000000018df1ca00 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) _addObserver:forProperty:options:context:] + 384 (NSKeyValueObserving.m:1604)
19  Foundation                      0x000000018df1bcb4 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverRegistration) addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] + 120 (NSKeyValueObserving.m:1823)
20  WebKit                          0x0000000198da2aec -[WKPreferenceObserver init] + 244 (PreferenceObserver.mm:156)
21  WebKit                          0x0000000198da29e8 +[WKPreferenceObserver sharedInstance] + 44 (PreferenceObserver.mm:107)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c922fd0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1454)
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c924ac8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c927a10 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 692 (inline_internal.h:2548)
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c935104 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 356 (inline_internal.h:2589)
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c9358e8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 116 (queue.c:6766)
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d42788cc _pthread_wqthread + 216 (pthread.c:2206)
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f77c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8c4eb48 __guarded_open_dprotected_np + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8c2ab78 guarded_open_dprotected_np + 36 (guarded_open_dprotected_np.c:44)
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a5bceaa4 robust_open2 + 292 (sqlite3.c:36142)
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a5b1fc74 unixOpen + 2000 (sqlite3.c:44571)
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a5b831d0 pager_write + 940 (sqlite3.c:23885)
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a5b86ac0 insertCell + 296 (sqlite3.c:64936)
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a5b862dc sqlite3BtreeInsert + 1844 (sqlite3.c:79966)
7   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a5b642e4 sqlite3VdbeExec + 29720 (sqlite3.c:97390)
8   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a5b5b7ac sqlite3_step + 304 (sqlite3.c:90618)
9   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001a5b22844 sqlite3_exec + 368 (sqlite3.c:130584)
10  AppOfCards                      0x00000001017d7ab4 0x100b28000 + 13302452
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c922fd0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1454)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c924ac8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c92bc08 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 580 (inline_internal.h:2548)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c92c734 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408 (queue.c:3862)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c936528 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 708 (queue.c:6590)
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4278908 _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2194)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f77c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f774 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8 name:
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8c2bdd0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8c2b184 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cca2cf8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 380 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cc9cea8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1216 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cc9c4bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   Foundation                      0x000000018df19e30 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 232 (NSRunLoop.m:374)
6   Foundation                      0x000000018df19d08 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92 (NSRunLoop.m:421)
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000018f6f0e94 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 516 (UIEventFetcher.m:834)
8   Foundation                      0x000000018e0840f0 __NSThread__start__ + 864 (NSThread.m:724)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4276ca8 _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:880)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f788 thread_start + 8

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8c503d0 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c925470 _dlock_wait + 56 (lock.c:326)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c92521c _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 56 (lock.c:366)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c932f54 __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 352 (lock.h:330)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c932b20 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 148 (queue.c:1738)
5   Accengage                       0x0000000102382acc 0x10235c000 + 158412
6   Accengage                       0x00000001023a9ffc 0x10235c000 + 319484
7   Accengage                       0x00000001023a97e4 0x10235c000 + 317412
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c924ac8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c9332a0 _dispatch_sync_invoke_and_complete + 60 (queue.c:998)
10  Accengage                       0x0000000102382b98 0x10235c000 + 158616
11  Accengage                       0x00000001023a96e8 0x10235c000 + 317160
12  Accengage                       0x000000010237beb0 0x10235c000 + 130736
13  Accengage                       0x00000001023775fc 0x10235c000 + 112124
14  Accengage                       0x0000000102375a7c 0x10235c000 + 105084
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c922fd0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1454)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c924ac8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c92bc08 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 580 (inline_internal.h:2548)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c92c734 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408 (queue.c:3862)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018c936528 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 708 (queue.c:6590)
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4278908 _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2194)
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f77c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f774 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f774 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12 name:
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8c2bdd0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8c2b184 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   FirebaseCrashlytics             0x0000000102724010 FIRCLSMachExceptionReadMessage + 56 (FIRCLSMachException.c:194)
3   FirebaseCrashlytics             0x0000000102724010 FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 104 (FIRCLSMachException.c:170)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4276ca8 _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:880)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f788 thread_start + 8

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f774 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 14 name:
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8c2bdd0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8c2b184 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cca2cf8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 380 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cc9cea8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1216 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cc9c4bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018d555050 +[__CFN_CoreSchedulingSetRunnable _run:] + 572 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1374)
6   Foundation                      0x000000018e0840f0 __NSThread__start__ + 864 (NSThread.m:724)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4276ca8 _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:880)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f788 thread_start + 8

Thread 15 name:
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8c4f75c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427a550 _pthread_cond_wait + 1192 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001a0e3ed28 std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::r... + 100 (__threading_support:396)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000196d4a874 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 528 (__mutex_base:0)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000196d4a364 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::Scavenger*) + 16 (Scavenger.cpp:395)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000196d4b828 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::Scavenger*), bmalloc::Scaveng... + 48 (type_traits:3545)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4276ca8 _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:880)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f788 thread_start + 8

Thread 16 name:
Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8c2bdd0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b8c2b184 mach_msg + 76 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cca2cf8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 380 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cc9cea8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1216 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018cc9c4bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018d555050 +[__CFN_CoreSchedulingSetRunnable _run:] + 572 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1374)
6   Foundation                      0x000000018e0840f0 __NSThread__start__ + 864 (NSThread.m:724)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4276ca8 _pthread_start + 320 (pthread.c:880)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f788 thread_start + 8

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d427f774 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000002900
    x8: 0x00000000000005b9   x9: 0x2728aa08fa46ff08  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x0000000000000003
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000003
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001023178c0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000407  x21: 0x00000001023179a0  x22: 0x0000000103cf4850  x23: 0x0000000000000007
   x24: 0x0000000002ffffff  x25: 0x00000001023179a0  x26: 0x00000000000020ff  x27: 0x0000000000000114
   x28: 0x000000028130cd40   fp: 0x000000016f2d6440   lr: 0x00000001d4277c74
    sp: 0x000000016f2d6420   pc: 0x00000001b8c4f98c cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

my application have both a swift and React code.

Any help please